# hibernate - could not execute statement; SQL [n/a] - saving nested object

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, save, hsqldb

I'm trying to save a nested object using hibernate and I receive `could not execute statement; SQL [n/a] Exception`

**CODE**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "listing")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Listing implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "listing_id")
  private String listingId;

  @Column(name = "property_type")
  private PropertyType propertyType;

  @Column(name = "category")
  private Category category;

  @Column(name = "price_currency")
  private String priceCurrency;

  @Column(name = "price_value")
  private Double priceValue;

  @Column(name = "map_point")
  private MapPoint mapPoint;

  @Column(name = "commission_fee_info")
  private CommissionFeeInfo commissionFeeInfo;
}


public class MapPoint implements Serializable {

  private final float latitude;
  private final float longitude;
}

public class CommissionFeeInfo implements Serializable {

  private String agentFeeInfo;
  private CommissionFeeType commissionFeeType;
  private Double value;
  private Double commissionFee;
}

public enum CommissionFeeType implements Serializable { }
```

Using `RazorSQL` I saw that `hibernate` defines `MapPoint` and `CommissionFee` as `VARBINARY`

What I can't understand, is the fact that hibernate manages to save it when commissionFeeInfo is not present. It has no problem with saving `MapPoint`

Does anyone have an idea about what I do wrong?

**UPDATE**

I found out that if all attributes of `CommissionFeeInfo` excepting `agentFeeInfo`are `null`, the object will be saved without problems. If one of the other attributes is `!= null`, the errors occur.

**UPDATE 2**

I changed the type of all attributes of `CommissionFeeInfo` into `String` and the object will be saved without problem, but I can't let the attributes as `String`.

Comment: Can you explain more the error you have? There are any nested exception? Any SQL error code?

Comment: @RicardoVila yes, there's a nested exceptions `java.sql.SQLDataException: data exception: string data, right truncation;  table: LISTING column: COMMISSION_FEE_INFO`

Comment: and also `org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement` and `sql = n/a`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding setting

```
@Column(name = "commission_fee_info", columnDefinition = "LONGVARBINARY")
```

as annotation for the field `commisionFeeInfo` in the class `Listing`

Answer (score 3):

For me,

```
@Column(columnDefinition="text")
```

solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

That solution could help for a different reason. One other reason could be Column length. Check your column length. I had the same error the reason was my data exceed the size of the column.

```
setSignInProvider("String length > 15 ")
```

Before

```
    @Column(name = "sing_in_provider", length = 15)
```

and then

```
   @Column(name = "sing_in_provider", length = 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue . and then I solved the problem

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`

Answer (score 0):

For me I'm using **current_date** for a field in my sql table. but this is a keyword in SQL so I can't use this name. I changed the field name to **current_date_and_time** it works for me. also I added the column name on my entity class.

```
@Column(name = "current_date_and_time")
```